# How can I simulate an extern Android Studio database?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql

I've got an app made with Android Studio. This app should have a connection to an external Database. I've got a lot of code, but i've got a problem with testing the app.

How can I simulate a phone Database? Are there any programms? (The Play Store mysql apps don't work)

Thank you :)

Comment: You could add some more details, including code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @rainer I don't have a Problem with my code. I only need a method to simulate a root server or anything else to test an extern android studio database connection.
I need a database simulator for phone